# Добавление двух слов в переменную массива структур

Tags: c++

Мне нужно записать в файл строку вида:

> Название техники, марка, дата приема, статус заказа.

Вот структура:

```
struct tech {
    char group[100], mark[100], date[100], succes[100];
} arr[100];
```

Вот часть кода:

```
int  i = 0;
cout << "Enter count of items";
cin >> n;
ofstream fout("file.txt");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Enter group, mark, date and succes" << endl;
    cin >> arr[i].group >> arr[i].mark >> arr[i].date >> arr[i].succes;
    fout << arr[i].group << " " << arr[i].mark << " " << arr[i].date << " " << arr[i].succes << endl;
}
fout.close();
```

Пример моего ввода:

> Телевизор Витязь 07.05.2019 не выполнен

Вывод в файл:

> Телевизор Витязь 07.05.2019 не

Вопрос: как мне записать в succes именно "не выполнено"

Comment: Если это С++, то почему массивы символов, а не `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `>>` считывает **слово**. Так что если б вы вводили "Телевизор Рубин М", все было бы еще хуже.

Читайте *строку* с помощью функции `getline` и уже ее делите на части так, как вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

std::cin >> *имя_переменной* считывает строку до первого пробела. Если вы хотите считать строку включая пробелы, то используйте std::getline().
Однако, неправильное использование std::getline() может привести к неожиданным результатам.
К примеру, если вы решите считать строку вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int someInt;
    std::cin >> someInt;

    std::string someString;
    std::getline(std::cin, someString);
    std::cout << someString << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

то вы успеете ввести только число, а затем программа сразу завершится и ничего не выведет.

Почему так?
Когда вы вводите данные с помощью std::cin, то создаётся буфер, который будет хранить вводимые символы с консоли. Как только вы нажимаете Enter, то в конец буфера добавится символ '\n'.

Как только вы вводите данные в переменную какого либо примитивного типа данных, то **cin >>**
 будет считывать символы последовательно из буфера друг за другом , пока он может записать их в эту переменную, а остальное останется в буфере. Например, если в буфере находится 348abracadabra45\n, то в переменную типа **int** запишется 348, а в буфере останется abracadabra45\n.

Вернёмся к нашему примеру.

Сначала вы записываете число в переменную типа **int**. Пускай буфер у вас был таким 23\n. Тогда после ввода в буфере останется только '\n'. Тогда **getline()** будет считывать данные в строку до того момента, пока не встретит символ '\n'. Таким образом, в нашу **someString** запишется ничего, т.к. в буфере у нас только перевод строки. Также стоит отметить, что после вызова getline() первый символ перевода строки исчезнет(и всё, что перед ним).

Как сделать так, чтобы всё ок считалось?

Пишем вот так вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int someInt;
   std::cin >> someInt;

   std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
   std::string someString;
   std::getline(std::cin, someString);
   return 0;
}
```

std::cin.ignore(short a, char c)сделает так, что будут игнорироваться первые **a** символов, пока не встретит символ **c**.

**UPD**.

Не заметил в начале, что вы используете строки в стиле C. Решение остаётся таким же, только используйте не std::getline(), а std::cin.getline(char *, short len).